# Shell Script: curl malformed body

Tags: shell, curl

I'm getting this error message:

> json parse error: invalid character 'E' after top-level value (202020207b202020202020226b696e64223a2022536563726574222c2020 ...)

I'm launching a curl statement from my shell script:

```
curl -k \
    -X PUT \
    -d @- \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/t-secret" <<'EOF'
    {
      "kind": "Secret",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "data": {
        "rabbit-password": "fromcontainer"
      }
    }
    EOF
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The here document delimiter cannot be indented, unless you use `<<-`, and even then, it can only be indented by one or more tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot indent the closing `EOF` with spaces.

```
curl -k \
    -X PUT \
    -d @- \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "$SERVER_URL/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/secrets/t-secret" <<'EOF'
    {
      "kind": "Secret",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "data": {
        "rabbit-password": "fromcontainer"
      }
    }
EOF
```